# How do you create a stub application that only directs users to download the full version on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

Just looking to create a stub application that does nothing but direct the user to download the full version on Google Play once the application is launched.

I'm assuming the stub apk will obviously need the same package name, signed with the same certificate but have a lower version code. All while only pointing to the Google Play product page. Is that all that's needed?

Can you have the apk update upon launch from Google Play without directing the user to initiate clicking the update button?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
final String appName = "com.example";
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id="+appName)));
```

Remember that user can have no GooglePlay Installed, in that case you want to catch ActivityNotFoundException (or something like that), and give link to browser.

Your app stub has to have same package name, and must be signed with same certificate as one in GooglePlay.

Comment: does anything need to change if the full version in Google Play is a paid app?

Comment: Well, i`m not 100% sure, but if package name is the same, it may work.

Comment: Regarding premium app..I just got confirmation from our liaison to Google and was told this is no longer possible since there is no proof of purchase. There is also the question of what will happen when users who back up their apps can sign into another device, that device will gain download for free. If anyone knows of a solution it would be great to share it. THanks!