# How to download full application version from Google Play using Stub application?

Tags: android, google-play

Using the following approach [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962431/how-do-you-create-a-stub-application-that-only-directs-users-to-download-the-ful) I have created Stub app. What I want is to deliver Stub app to act as pre-installed application (link which leads to Google Play's full version of app). Since I have app on GooglePlay version 2.0.0 my idea was to create Stub app with lower version and deliver it to reseler, if somebody wants to use app he will run Stub app which will lead user to GooglePlay and from there user should see 2 options: "uninstall" and "update". Notice that update actually should install full version of app and overwrite the Stub app, this step should be transparent for the user.
Problem is the following: insted of "uninstall" and "update" I got "uninstall" and "open" options in Google Play, so when I hit open in Google Play it runs Stub app then Stub app open GooglePlay and so on. I'm not able use full version of app until Stub app has been uninstalled.a

Does anyone tried something similar, or have some other approach how to achieve my idea?

Comment: What's the point here?  If you're preinstalled, pre install the full version.  If not, how are you going to be installed other than going to the play store?  Keep in mind only a tiny number of users will ever download your app through a "stub" app.  I know I'd advise against it, it just sounds kind of off.

Comment: @GabeSechan I'm totally agree with you, but it's Reseller's requirement. This only have sense if the full app has insane amount of MB (size > 100 MB), so in this way pre-installed app will take ~1.5 MB, but again this is not case here.

Answer (score 0):

While this seems like a bad idea (your solution to having a large download is to essentially have a small download in addition to the already large download), this would be your general workflow:

Your stub app has a version code of X, or 1 for this example.

*Every* apk published to Google Play has a higher version code.

They share the same package name and keystore.

This should result in the user being offered an update button when they use the stub app to launch the Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep version number of stub app lesser than version code which is on play store.