# Differentiate between stub app and downloaded app

Tags: java, android, google-play

One of our clients has a deal with an OEM. Our Stub app will be preinstalled on their android devices. Stub application will act as a placeholder.[I went throught this link to create stub app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17962431/how-do-you-create-a-stub-application-that-only-directs-users-to-download-the-ful). I want to differentiate b/w the user who installs full version of the app via stub application and the user who installs directly from playstore.

Users of pre-installed stub app will offer free trial for X months. Other users who do not have stub app preinstalled on their device will directly download from playstore and will not receive any benifits.

The stub app provided to OEM wont be installed as System app, but will come pre-loaded with the device. 
As my stub app is not system app, it can be uninstalled by the user. [I had gone through this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784505/how-do-i-check-if-an-app-is-a-non-system-app-in-android) but it is a difference b/w system app and non-system app.

Now how can i differentiate whether the full version of my application is installed via stub app or installed directly from playstore, so that I can give free trail for respective users.

Please guide me in achieving this.
As this is my first question on SO, I apologize for any mistakes.

Comment: You could pass parameters from the stub app to the playstore version.  Smth like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466443/how-to-use-app-links-to-pass-parameter-to-android-playstore-to-be-retrieved-when/25466879

Comment: Thank you @sinek for taking out time and answering to my question :) I will look into this.

Comment: Hi @sinek, what if user installs app from other stores eg : OEM stores, in that case we don't know whether that store returns referral like play store. And also even if i install via playstore, I have to save referral ID some where local(shared preference).. what if user clears the cache?

Comment: Is there some thing like flag which i can set in stub App(lets say old versions) and can retrieve in new versions of the app?

Comment: I guess you can store an encoded data into a local file and read it from new app or smth like that.

Comment: Thanks @sinek.. one quick question..Can't I store some thing in (say manifest / gradle) or any other resource apart from shared preference and local storage in old version  and access it in new version.

Comment: or is there something that i can differentiate b/w system app(installed in ROM), pre-installed app(pre-loaded by OEM but not as system app) and downloaded app?